# Angular v8 no aplica la hoja css MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled

Tags: css, angular

Estoy intentando aplicar estilos de manera dinámica, y para ello quiero cambiar el estilo desde el index.html desde aquí:

```
 <link  class="main-theme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="assets/demo-style.css" >
```

Esta todo importado de manera correcta en el **`angular.json`**. El path es correcto, lo lee la web.

Sin embargo me aparece el error:

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/assets/demo-style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled

¿Alguna corrección o cosa que se me escape?

Gracias

Comment: Verifica, desde el propio navegador, que tienes acceso a http://localhost:4200/assets/demo-style.css

Comment: El problema es que tu servidor está devolviendo el fichero CSS pero indicando que su función no es ser una hoja de estilos sino un fichero de texto plano sin ninguna función especial. Si lo tienes en el fichero de angular.json, elimínalo de tu index.html

Comment: Hola, si puedo acceder.
Por otro lado, en el angular.json lo tengo importado con el injectable a false.